# Multiple Foreach Loop Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, foreach, codeigniter-3, foreach-loop-container

I want to display data in different sections, but error when I run.

[image]

Controller

```
class Dfkamar extends CI_Controller {
public function index() {
    $data['tamu'] = $this ->m_tamu->daftar_kamar()->result();
        $this->load->view('templates/header');
        $this->load->view('templates/sidebar');
        $this->load->view('dfkamar', $data);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer');
}
```

View

```
    <?php
      foreach ($tamu as $tamu) : 
    ?>

        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success"><?php echo $tamu->gateA ?></button>
      </div>  
      <?php endforeach;?>

    <?php
        foreach ($tamu as $tamu1) : 
      ?>

        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success"><?php echo $tamu1->gateB ?></button>
      </div>  
      <?php endforeach;?>
```

Comment: One thing I would always avoid is something like `$tamu as $tamu`, using the same variable twice makes no sense.

Comment: so, just write $tamu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$tamu array variable get replaced $tamu string in first foreach so dont't do that

working code is as below:

```
$tamu = ['gateA'=>'test-A','gateB'=>'sdfs'];

      foreach ($tamu as $tamu_item) : 
        echo $tamu_item->gateA;
     endforeach;
     
     var_dump($tamu);

    foreach ($tamu as $tamu1) : 
        echo $tamu1->gateB;
     endforeach;
```

Comment: $tamu = ['gateA'=>'test-A','gateB'=>'sdfs'];
Replace at Controller or what?

Comment: foreach ($tamu as $tamu-> here you have defined iterated item variable same as array same so after foreach array replaced with last item.